# Jupyter notebook monospace font doesn't render properly in Safari

Tags: css, fonts, safari, jupyter-notebook, monospace

When I use Jupyter notebook in Safari, I found that the monospace font (both in the cells and in the output results) do not render properly. Instead of using a monospace font, they simply appear in a San Serif font. However, if I open the same page in Chrome, there's no problem displaying monospcace font. I have not changed the CSS settings in Safari. How can Safari display the fonts in Jupyter notebook correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey, can you share source code to we can debug!